# Issue with units when using Turf.js to calculate area

Tags: javascript, area, units-of-measurement, measurement, turfjs

I know Turf.js was created for geospatial analysis of georeferenced data, but I'm wondering if I can use it to analyse features in a cartesian space.

For example, I need to calculate the area of a very simple rectangle, as follows:

```
turf.area(
  turf.polygon([ [[0,1], [0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,1]] ])
)
```

The result I get from the above calculation is `12391399902.071104`, which I understand are square meters. It is also clear that Turf.js is reading `[0,1], [0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,1]` as WGS84 coordinates and what I am looking for is a way to tell Turf.js that these are not geographic coordinates but linear measures in cartesian space.

I know from the specs (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#page-12) that GeoJSON works only with WGS84 and what I'm looking for is probably an improper use of Turf.js itself.

Finally, my question: is there a way in Turf.js of measuring the area of a rectangle with coordinates `[0,1], [0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,1]` in meters (or whatever linear unit) and obtaining `1` m2 (or whatever square linear unit)?

Comment: It's not possible with turf.js, but it's possible with https://github.com/alexbol99/flatten-js

Comment: @AnatolySukhanov, thank you. I will have a look. For the moment I implemented it with d3.js, but flatten also looks quite interesting.

Comment: It is possible with turf.js! You have to convert the projection to wgs84 using turf's function toWgs84(): https://turfjs.org/docs/#toWgs84. Then you can use area as expected